# aplicar estrategia bot de tradingview en real

Tags: bot

he intentado aplicar la estrategia que he creado en un grafico en real pero no me abre operaciones en real es como si abriese oiperaciones pero siempre en simulado, estoy dentro de la cuenta real y he agregado mi estrategia al grafico de la cuenta en real con dinero real, abre operaciones pero no parece ser nada en real ya que en el listado de operaciones del broker IBKR no abre nada

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.